# Count the number of inversions in an array that is sorted in increasing order then decreasing order

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

Given an array that is sorted in increasing order then decreasing order eg: {1, 3, 5, 4, 2}, I want to find the number of inversions required to sort this array in O(n). This is my code which sorts such arrays in O(n):

```
void sort(long* a, long* result, long n)
 {
      long* start = &a[0];
      long* end = &a[n - 1];
      long count = 0;
      while (start <= end) {
        if (*start < *end) {
            result[count] = *start;
            start += 1;
        }
        else {
           result[count] = *end;
           end -= 1;
       }
      }
  }
```

In my code, I used 2 pointers from the start and end and stored the sorted array into the result array. How do I count the number of inversions using a similar algorithm?

Comment: Please define "inversion"

Comment: Probably you mean *swap* for  *inversion*, and you want to know the minimum number of required swap ? `How do I count the number of inversions using a similar algorithm?` : because your way to sort does not invert (swap) elements it cannot be used to count the number of required inversions (swaps).

Comment: You may like to read the [Wikipedia article about Cycle sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this algorithm from "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/":
Algorithm:

1. Traverse through the array from start to end.
2. For every element find the count of elements smaller than the current number upto that index using another loop.
3. Sum up the count of inversion for every index.
4. Print the count of inversions. 

   You can also find a code example on their website.

Moreover, for your function it seems that you JUST need a new variable to store the number of oinversions you do.

Hope it helped!